# Back Populate ActiveRecord UUIDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to back populate an ActiveRecord model with uuids. There are approximately 500K records.

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
clause = ['uuid is null and created_at >= ?', DateTime.new(2017, 8, 15)]
MyTable.where(clause) do |record|
  record.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
  record.save
end
```

This is inefficient given it creates multiple update statements.

I looked at [update_all](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) but the update portion appears to only be evaluated once, so the same UUID is set for all records.

```
MyTable.where(clause).update_all(uuid: SecureRandom.uuid)
```

Is there a way to do a bulk update with these conditions and generate a new UUID for each?

Comment: Take a look at `ActiveRecord::Batches`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

Comment: @MrYoshiji Perfect. `find_each` is working great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Batches` is meant to do that : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

> Looping through a [large] collection of records [...] is very inefficient since it will try to instantiate all the objects at once.
>
> [...] Batch processing methods allow you to work with the records in batches, thereby greatly reducing memory consumption.
>
> The find_each method uses [...] a batch size of 1000 (or as specified by the :batch_size option).

```
Person.find_each do |person| # will only load 1000 records at a time
  person.do_awesome_stuff
end
```

Comment: This would be the way to go for writing values that only ruby can produce. But databases are perfectly capable of generating UUIDs, so it should be just one UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL database, then this should do the trick in the most efficient way:

```rb
MyTable.where(clause).update_all('uuid = UUID()')
```

Comment: And postgres has `gen_random_uuid()`. This should be the accepted answer.